# Loading a module with dependencies in utop

Tags: ocaml, utop

I have two modules `A.ml` and `B.ml` like so:

`A.ml`:

```
type t = int
let from_int (i : int) : t = i
```

`B.ml`:

```
open A
let my_t : t = from_int 0
```

I can compile them just fine by invoking `ocamlc A.ml B.ml` however I have no idea how to load them both in `utop` in order to use `my_t` interactively. Using:

- `utop -init B.ml` yields `Error: Reference to undefined global 'A'`
- `utop` followed by `#use "A.ml";;` and `#use "B.ml";;` leads to the same error
- removing `open A` from `B.ml` makes this double `#use` work but `ocamlc A.ml B.ml` now fails on `B` with `Error: Unbound type constructor t`.

Comment: `#use` is for direct inclusion - to dump a file into the toplevel as a _module_, you want `#mod_use`. There's also ocamlmktop, which constructs a toplevel with a bunch of modules linked into it. And finally there is `#load` as given in Pierre's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to compile first a.ml :

```
  ocamlc -c a.ml  // yields a.cmo
```

in utop :

```
  #load "a.cmo";;
  #use "b.ml";;
```

Comment: I see. It's even possible to throw these into an `init.ml` and use `utop -init init.ml` in order not to have to invoke these commands each time you start `utop`. Thanks!